# Android studio - How to view which functions of which objects are being called?

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently, I'm using Log.d in each function to see if it is being called. That's tiresome. Are there any Android Studio's built-in functionalities that allow me to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use debugger with break points

[image]

[image]